# How do I add a network user into my file permissions?

Tags: networking, windows-8, user-accounts, file-permissions

I have a folder (in particular, a "User Home" folder) that I would like to give access to a local account.

For example, My laptop's local name is called "PC", for some apparent reason.
It is also connected to a network called "NETWORK". It's configured to have both local and network accounts.
**Of course, those aren't the actual names of the network/computer.**

So, how do I add a network account into the file permissions?
I am connected to the network and only my PC shows up as a possible network object.
(Yes, logging out and using [Network Name]/[Username] for login does allow you to log in with a network account).

EDIT: Basicially -
**Why can't I add my network profile onto the permissions list (while logged onto the local profile) THUS while I'm on my network account - why I can't add my local account into the permissions list?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that by "network" you really mean "domain"? If you are in a domain, you can grant access to domain accounts by entering them as

domainname\username

for example, NTDEV\davec

You enter the account ("object") name by typing it, just as above, into the "Select User or Group" dialog and and then clicking "Check Names". If it's ok, your entry will suddenly be underlined. OK from that dialog and then set the permissions (access rights) you want to grant, OK out, etc.

Comment: Yes, but the domains does not appear, and the textfield is grayed (disabled).

Comment: This is on a share? You have to set up your directory (ok, ok, "folder") as a share first. You may however be prevented from doing this, or from setting permissions on the share, or from setting permissions even on your own directories for that matter, by group policy set by your domain admin.

Comment: n.b.: You type the string (e.g. NTDEV\davec) into the "Enter the object names" field, not "From this location". I know it doesn't look like a normal text entry field...

Comment: I'm not sharing a directory. I'm using file permissions. (Security tab in folder/file properties), and my "From this location:" field is grayed out.

Comment: You can't use file permissions to allow network access to a directory on your machine. You must first create a share of the directory (folder). Until you do that the folder is flatly not visible outside of your system. Then you control users' access to the share via the Permissions settings _for the share_. While you're in that dialog, I would advise removing "Everyone"'s access completely.

Comment: Some part of a night's sleep later... ok, I see *I misread the question.* Your "network user" is logging in locally _to your machine_, either physically at your machine or via Remote Desktop or something similar, yes? But they're using their domain credentials to log in?

Comment: Two users; one is local (on the computer), and the other is a network roaming profile. So why can't the roaming profile add a local profile into the permissions/a local account add a domain; network account into the permissions?

Comment: I know it's a long time, but the correct answer, as you said is to enter [COMPUTER NAME]\\[USERNAME] while on the networked account, or [DOMAIN]\\[USERNAME] on the local account.